# EF error: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, триггер

Есть метод, который добавляет запись в БД

```
    public void AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**В параметры передается экземпляр класса Post.**

Для таблицы Posts создан триггер, который обращается к другой БД, где хранятся данные о пользователях и соответственно осуществляет поиск.

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @UserId NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT UserId FROM inserted)
DECLARE @Content NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT Content FROM inserted)
DECLARE @PublishTime DATE = (SELECT PublishTime FROM inserted)

SELECT @UserId = (SELECT Id  --Поиск пользователя в таблице AspNetUsers
FROM SlackIdentityDB.dbo.AspNetUsers
WHERE Id = @UserId);

IF @UserId IS NOT NULL --Если пользователь найден
  INSERT INTO Posts(UserId,Content,PublishTime) VALUES(@UserId,@Content,@PublishTime);
ELSE ROLLBACK;

END
```

Однако при запуске приложения генерируется исключение
[image: Ошибка]

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как по традиции, отвечу на свой вопрос сам.Эта проблема решается добавлением в конец триггера select-запроса с параметрами(`@@ROWCOUNT > 0 and Id = scope_identity()`)

```
SELECT Id
FROM *Таблица, для которой создается триггер*
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and Id = scope_identity();
```

Comment: Если бы еще добавляли код в виде кода, а не (по традиции) в виде картинки - было бы совсем хорошо. Это значительно повышает шанс ответа - никто не станет перепечатывать ваш код, и, тем более, никто не будет перепечатывать текст с картинки исключения, чтобы поискать хоть что-то связанное с вашим вопросом. Ну и да, для будущих посетителей ваш вопрос тоже бесполезен - т.к. поиск по коду в картинке не работает.

Comment: @PashaPash В названии указан текст исключения, так что по этому поводу можете не беспокоиться. Код привел в виде картинки, т.к. SO не правильно форматировал его, по крайней мере у меня не удалось(извиняюсь, если причинил неудобства).

Comment: форматирование - выделяете код, нажимаете Ctrl+k. Или просто вручную добавляете 4 пробела перед кодом.